# bot framework and Microsoft teams - how to get all channels associated to a team?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I am trying to get all channels associated with a specific team so that my bot can send proactive messages.  Based on the reading I've done, I need to use the FetchChannelList method in the Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Teams namespace, in the TeamsOperationsExtensions class.

If I do this:

`var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
ConversationList channels = connector.GetTeamsConnectorClient().Teams.FetchChannelList(activity.GetChannelData<TeamsChannelData>().Team.Id);`

channels is null.  If I break it down to only  connector.GetTeamsConnectorClient(), that is not null, but  connector.GetTeamsConnectorClient().Teams.FetchChannelList(activity.GetChannelData().Team.Id) is.

To break it down further, I tried to get activity.GetChannelData().  Only the Tenant property is not null.  All the others (Channel, Team, EventType and Notification) are null.

I am using tunnelrelay, which forwards messages sent to the bot's public endpoint to a private endpoint, and am using tenant filter authentication in the messages controller.  Not sure if that would cause any problems?  (When I watch messages coming in through tunnel relay, I see there too that only Tenant is the only channeldata property which is not null.  Here's what I see in tunnelrelay: 
`"entities":[{"locale":"en- US","country":"US","platform":"Windows","type":"clientInfo"}],"channelData":{"tenant":{"id":"our_tenant_id"}}}`

Also, regarding the teamID expected as a parameter to the FetchChannelList method, how do I find out what that is for a given team other than the GetChannelData() method?   I tried the powershell cmdlet Get-Team (for example: Get-Team -User me@abc.com).  It returns a distinct groupId for each team I am a part of, but I'm assuming groupId != TeamId.  Is that correct? And, where can I find the teamId that the FetchChannelList is expecting other than the GetChannelData method?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here was that the message to the bot (the activity) was a direct message, not a part of a channel conversation.  Apparently, the Channel and Team properties are only available in a channel conversation.

Also, regarding the team ID, one way to get it outside of code is to click the "..." next to the team and click "get link to team".  You will see something like: 
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/team/19%3a813345c7fafe437e8737057505224dc3%40thread.skype/conversations?groupId=Some_GUID&tenantId=Some_GUID

The line after team/ (19%3a813345c7fafe437e871111115934th3%40thread.skype) contains the teamId, but not exactly.  If you replace the first % and the two characters immediately following it with : and the second % and the two characters immediately following it with @, that is your teamid.  So, from:

19%3a813345c7fafe437e871111115934th3%40thread.skype

the team ID is:

19:813345c7fafe437e871111115934th3@thread.skype